# Why is re.search not getting the right group while re.findall is getting it?

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy, regex-group

Given the string `abc.` the aim is to break it into two groups `abc` and `.`. Actually, I'm only interested in the group before the `.`.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'abc.'
>>> re.search('^(\S+)\.$', text).group(0)
'abc.'
>>> re.findall('^(\S+)\.$', text)
['abc']
```

**Why is re.search not getting the right group while re.findall is getting it?**

Another example where the input is `abc.def.`, the expect output is to isolate the final fullstop and get `abc.def` and `.`. So `re.findall` is getting it as desired:

```
>>> re.findall('^(\S+)\.$', text)
['abc.def']
```

But `re.search` lumps the final fullstop into the first group.

```
>>> re.search('^(\S+)\.$', text).group(0)
'abc.def.'
```

**Is it possible for `re.search('^(\S+)\.$', text).group(0)` to return only `abc.def`? Is there some flags that needs to be set?**

Comment: Group numbers start at 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are asking for the wrong group. Group 0 is the entire match, which includes the dot. Group 1 is the first capture group within the match. This is all spelled out in the docs for the [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) object, which `re.search` returns. If you absolutely need something zero-based, use `re.search(...).groups()[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Group numbers start at 1, so you want `group(1)`. `group(0)` is the entire match text.